# How to shift characters without using IndexOf or Substring?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I shift characters of a string with the Shift Operator (>>), and without using Substring and IndexOf?

For example, I would like every-second character in a string to be shifted right (or left) by 1.

E.g.

Each iteration should move a character to the right, just once:

```
baeltazor
abeltazor
aebltazor
aelbtazor
aeltbazor
aeltabzor
aeltazbor
aeltazobr
aeltazorb
```

And then it would continue until every character has shifted to the end of the string once.

And then it would continue until every character has shifted to the end of the string once.

Comment: How do you shift every second character without moving or overwriting all the others? Please give sample input/output.

Comment: You would have to overload the shift operator.  Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7586887.  Why are you prevented from using Substring and IndexOf?  Is this some sort of obscure homework assignment?

Comment: keep in mind, you can't change strings, you can only create a new string transformed in some way from the original

Comment: @RobertHarvey - you should not be able to overload any operator for existing type (likle `string`)... or I'm not getting your suggestion?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Well, maybe I'm not getting the OP's question.  Is this supposed to be a bitshift on some characters in the string, and not a positional shift?  Doesn't make much sense, really.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make my question very clear. My fault. I am updating the question.

Comment: I think it's more bitshift but slightly different.

Comment: Your example doesn't make much sense in the context of your question. Your just shifting one character to the end...

Answer (score 3):

It's probably easiest to use the `string.ToCharArray()` method to get an array of characters, and then manipulate the array in an O(n) traversal, then return it to string via the `ToString()` method. Manipulating a string would be very inefficient because strings are immutable and every change would create a new string object.

An example of shifting to the left or whatever:

```
var myString = "hello";
// Create char array
var myStringArray = myString.ToCharArray();

// Iterate the array of chars
for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.Length; i++)
{
    // Only every second index
    if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
        // Swap chars
        var tempChar = myStringArray[i];
        myStringArray[i] = myStringArray[i-1];
        myStringArray[i-1] = tempChar;
    }
}

// String result
var result = new string(myStringArray);
```